# Can I set a custom ringtone and vibration pattern for a firebase notification?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

Recently I started coding my first android project that includes Firebase Cloud Messaging. I use Android SDK 21 (Android 5).

My intention is to let the user choose, which ringtone shall be played and if the device shall vibrate. To do so I created a helper class `SettingsHandler`, that accesses the user settings like so:

```
public synchronized static Uri getRingtoneUri(Context context) {
    Sharedpreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("table_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return Uri.parse(prefs.getString("ringtone_key"), RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION).toString());
}

public synchronized static boolean shouldVibrateOnPush(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("table_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return prefs.getBoolean("vibration_flag", true);
}
```

So when I receive a Notification from Firebase I want to set the sound and the vibrate pattern that the user can set using the methods above.

To get this, I override the `onMessageReceived` method in `MyFirebaseMessagingService` that extends - who expected this - `FirebaseMessagingService`:

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage msg) {
    super.onMessageReceived(msg);
    if (msg.getNotification() != null) {
        Intent activityIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, REQUEST_CODE, activityIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Notification note = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "channel_id")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.icon)
                .setContentTitle(msg.getNotification().getTitle())
                .setContentText(msg.getNotification().getBody())
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setSound(SettingsHandler.getRingtoneUri(this))
                .setVibrate(SettingsHandler.shouldVibrateOnPush ? new long[] {500, 500, 500, 500, 500} : new long[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0})
                .build();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            //create notification channels
        }
        NotificationManagerCompat manager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        manager.notify(1, note);
    }
}
```

However when I send a notification, the default sound always gets played, so I started asking myself, if i have some errors in my way of thinking. Any way how to do it properly? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this :
You can pick ringtone using below code:

```
selsound_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {   
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, "Select ringtone for notifications:");
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_SILENT, false);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_DEFAULT, true);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, currentUri);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE,RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    startActivityForResult( intent, 999);  
        }
    });
```

You then need to handle the currentUri in onActivityResult method and store it in sharedPreferences for future usage.

The actual work goes here :

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 999){
            if (data != null) {
                currentUri = data.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);
            }
            if (Settings.System.canWrite(this)){
                RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION, currentUri);
            }else {
                Intent settings = new Intent("android.settings.action.MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS");
                startActivityForResult(settings, 124);
            }
        }
        if (requestCode == 124){
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION, currentUri);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now get the uri from stored sharedPreferences and use in notification as :

```
 notification.setSound(currentUri);
        notification.setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 }));
```

**Note** : You need to have WRITE_SETTINGS permission for this task.

Comment: Will this use the ringtone I can select via `RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER` ? This is the way the user can select a ringtone in my app.

Comment: @procra i have edited the answer, this approach works, let me know if there is any query. :)

Comment: this is exactly the way I'm already doing it. However the sound didn't actually get set. Maybe the frame of my Uri is invalid. It looks like `"content://media/internal/audio/media/31"` but that seems correct for me.

Comment: @procra finally i was able to resolve this, edited answer will definitely work, the left work is to store currentUri in sharedPreferences. Hope this work at your end too. :)

Answer (score 0):

create the Resource folder (directory **res**)name it **raw** and put the file (sound file name.mp3) in it and than using the following code for custom sound

```
Notification note;
.....
......
note.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+context.getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.filename);//file name you want to play
```

for the **Oreo and higher SKD version** you need to put in Notification Channel

```
Uri sounduri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.filename); //file name you want to play

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

        NotificationChannel Channel = new NotificationChannel("CHANNEL_ID","CHANNEL NAME", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
        AudioAttributes attributes;
        .... 
        ........
        Channel.setSound(sounduri, attributes); //set the sound


        if (notificationManager != null){
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(Channel);}
    }
```

**OR**
using the MediaPlayer class to play sound for notification

```
MediaPlayer sound = MediaPlayer.create(contex, R.raw.filename);
sound.start();
```